# Why I'm getting exception InvalidOperationException when trying to play animation clips?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public static class IListExtensions
{
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> ts)
    {
        var count = ts.Count;
        var last = count - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < last; ++i)
        {
            var r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(i, count);
            var tmp = ts[i];
            ts[i] = ts[r];
            ts[r] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

public class PlayAnimations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;
    private AnimationClip[] clips;
    private List<AnimationClip> clipsList = new List<AnimationClip>();
    private string[] names;

    private void Awake()
    {
        clips = animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips;

        for (int i = 0; i < clips.Length; i++)
        {
            if (clips[i].name.Contains("mixamo"))
            {
                clipsList.Add(clips[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        if (clipsList.Count > 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(PlayRandomly());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator PlayRandomly()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            clipsList.Shuffle();

            foreach (var randClip in clipsList)
            {
                animator.Play(randClip.name);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(randClip.length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception message:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

On the line:

```
foreach (var randClip in clipsList)
```

I'm trying to play all the animation clips that contains `maximo`.

The only play I'm calling the method Init and start playing the animations is in this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimatorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator[] animators;
    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 1f;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public bool slowDown = false;
    public PlayAnimations playanimation;

    private bool endRot = false;
    private Vector3 center;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        center = target.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;

        for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(animators[2].transform.position, target.position);

        for(int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            animators[2].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(animators[2].transform.position, center, 0);
        }

        if (slowDown)
        {
            if (distanceFromTarget < 10)
            {
                float speed = (distanceFromTarget / 10) / 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
                {
                    animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
                }
            }
        }

        if (distanceFromTarget < 5f)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
            {
                //animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", 0);
                animators[i].SetBool("Idle", true);
                playanimation.Init();
            }

            if (!endRot)
            {
                Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);
                float angleToGoal = Quaternion.Angle(
                        goalRotation,
                        animators[0].transform.localRotation);
                float angleThisFrame = Mathf.Min(angleToGoal, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

                // use axis of Vector3.down to keep angles positive for ease of use
                animators[0].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, angleThisFrame);
                animators[1].transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, angleThisFrame);

                // We end if we rotated the remaining amount.
                endRot = (angleThisFrame == angleToGoal);
            }
            {
                animators[0].SetBool("Rifle Aiming Idle", true);
                animators[1].SetBool("Rifle Aiming Idle", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the line inside the Update:

```
playanimation.Init();
```

Comment: Tried your script and can not reproduce it. Is there anything else that alters the `randClip` list within the foreach loop like adding or removing items?

Comment: Look at the error message. What does it tell you? It tells you that "enumeration operation may not execute" because a "collection was modified."  Now, as you pointed out, the exception is thrown here: `foreach (var randClip in clipsList)`. So, what collection might be involved in this error? Where (and when) do you modify that collection? If you figured this out, you will then need to figure out (and that is the much harder part of the troubleshooting you will have to do) why the method that is modifying the collection is called while the `foreach (var randClip in clipsList)` loop is executing

Comment: As said as you posted it it works for me see [here](https://imgur.com/a/L362IaI)

Comment: I added to my question the only other script that call the method Init and start playing the animations. But I'm not sure why this is should be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting your Coroutine multiple times within the `Update` of the `AnimatorController` in

```
if (distanceFromTarget < 5f)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            //animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", 0);
            animators[i].SetBool("Idle", true);
            playanimation.Init();
        }
//...
```

allways on the same component `PlayAnimations playanimation`. Additionally this is placed in `Update` so might get called even more often.

This gives you multiple concurrent Coroutines manipulating the same value `clipsList`:

One routine might currently already be executing the `foreach` loop while a second couroutine changes the content of `clipsList` in

```
clipsList.Shuffle();
```

This is not "allowed" -> See your exception

---

Make sure you run the routine only once:

```
private bool wasInitialized;

public void Init()
{
    // Only start the coroutine if not initialized yet
    if (!wasInitialized && clipsList.Count > 0)
    {
        wasInitialized = true;
        StartCoroutine(PlayRandomly());
    }
}
```

or/and in general optimize the `AnimatorController` to avoid those redundant calls at all.

Comment: This is working fine for this error but now I'm getting warnings in the editor for each time it's trying to play animation inside the while loop on the line: animator.Play(randClip.name); The warnings are: Invalid Layer Index '-1' All this mixamo animations are in a SubStateMachine not in another layer. But when I put a breakpoint in the end of the Awake I see that clips contains all the mixamo animation clips. So I'm not sure why this warning/s ? This avoiding from playing the clips.

Comment: @DubiDuboni I don't know your complete setup. For me it is working (see [here](https://imgur.com/a/NAISOn4)) also when I place the states/clips inside of a sub-statemachine (`subMachine`). I don't get any warning or error.